# Merging and Searching JSON Arrays Using a SQLITE Query

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a new SQLite project and I am having trouble figuring out the syntax for a query.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to combine the data points for similar events and then get a count/percentage of the data points that fall between a certain threshold.

Currently I have a SQLite DB setup like this -

| name | data (json) |
| --- | --- |
| Event1 | [85.9, 83.5, 83.6, 85.6, 87.1, 86.0, 82.1, 84.2, 86.1, 85.0, 86.6, 84.0] |
| Event1 | [87.3, 87.8, 87.7, 81.5, 85.2, 84.1, 86.5, 80.3, 83.6, 86.3, 92.4, 84.9] |
| Event2 | [81.5, 82.2, 84.0, 83.2, 83.8, 83.3, 85.1, 85.0, 82.2, 88.4, 84.1, 85.6] |
| Event3 | [80.7, 79.0, 73.0, 68.7, 58.6, 60.1, 68.3, 67.1, 76.8, 76.7, 78.9, 56.8] |
| Event3 | [89.0, 85.3, 85.4, 84.0, 83.4, 84.9, 84.7, 88.9, 82.7, 81.9, 85.5, 83.8] |
| Event2 | [88.0, 86.4, 81.0, 88.1, 84.2, 84.4, 85.3, 86.4, 85.2, 87.9, 82.0, 90.1] |

Using this query - `SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(data) from data2 GROUP by name`

I can get the event arrays to append to each other like so -

| name | data (json) |
| --- | --- |
| Event1 | [[xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x]] |
| Event2 | [[xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x]] |
| Event3 | [[xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x], [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x]] |

But, in order to accomplish the second part of what I need, I think I need to have all the numbers into a single array instead of an array of arrays - something more like this -

| name | data (json) |
| --- | --- |
| Event1 | [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x] |
| Event2 | [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x] |
| Event3 | [xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x, xx.x] |

And that's definitely where I am stuck - how would I perform a search/count query to determine what percentage of the data points for each Event fell between 75 and 85?

Thank you guys for all your help

Comment: Be a lot simpler if each event+number was its own row.

Comment: @Shawn - I considered that originally, but there are 5 other columns in this table with a lot of repeat information. Doing it the way above condensed the table from 2billion rows down to 80million rows (and 6gb's to 1gb) which has decreased my other query times dramatically. With that being said, I have a few better filters so maybe the 2billion might be less of an issue. But it should be possible to at least return a single array right? `GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_EXTRACT(())` or something along those lines?  I might be able to offload the calculating part to the backend code itself.